# CHANGE event block SUBMIT event when I show/hide some HTML from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

I have a problem. I am attaching a codepen with the code for a sample.

If I enter a value smaller than 50 into the input and **immediately** click the send button, the `CHANGE` event is called, an error message is displayed and the value in the input is overwritten to the smallest possible value, but the `SUBMIT` event does not occur. If I again enter a value lower than 50, both the `CHANGE` event and the `SUBMIT` event will now be triggered.

If I now give a value that is within the allowed range of 50 - 150, the error message will disappear and only the `CHANGE` event will occur again. If I give a number from the allowed range again, the `CHANGE` event and `SUBMIT` event are called.

And I just need to solve so that the `submit` event is always called.

```js
const $form = $(".test-form");
const max = 150;
const min = 50;

$form
  .on("change", "input", function () {
    console.log("change");

    const setVal = $(this).val();

    if (setVal < min) {
      $(this).val(min);
      $(".error-min").show();
    }
    if (setVal > max) {
      $(this).val(max);
      $(".error-max").show();
    }
    if (setVal >= min) {
      $(".error-min").hide();
    }
    if (setVal <= max) {
      $(".error-max").hide();
    }
  })
  .on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit");
  });
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="test-form">
  <input type="number" value="100">
  <p class="error error-min">under min val (50)</p>
  <p class="error error-max">under max val (150)</p>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

https://codepen.io/dominiklev/pen/rNvOGPY

Comment: Put your validation logic in a function which is invoked both when the `change` event occurs on a field and also when the form is submit. If the validation fails, prevent the submission.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I don't need to prevent the submit, I need the SUBMIT to happen even if the CHANGE event happens, which will show/hide the message

Comment: Ah understood. The problem is because the button moves. Taking the events in turn, the change event happens first, shows the red validation message and the button shifts down. The click event then misses the button.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are a genius! You are a freaking genius! Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the button moves. Taking the events in turn, the `change` event happens first, shows the red validation message and the `button` shifts down. The user clicking the mouse then misses the `button`, so no `click` event is raised.

A quick fix to avoid this happening would be to change the `p` elements in to an inline element so that they appear alongside the `input` elements, a `span` for example:

```js
const $form = $(".test-form");
const max = 150;
const min = 50;

$form.on("change", "input", function() {
  const setVal = $(this).val();
  console.log('change');

  if (setVal < min) {
    $(this).val(min);
    $(".error-min").show();
  }
  if (setVal > max) {
    $(this).val(max);
    $(".error-max").show();
  }
  if (setVal >= min) {
    $(".error-min").hide();
  }
  if (setVal <= max) {
    $(".error-max").hide();
  }
}).on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit");
});
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

.error {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="test-form">
  <input type="number" value="100">
  <span class="error error-min">under min val (50)</span>
  <span class="error error-max">under max val (150)</span>
  <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```